# Troubleshooting my confirmatory factor analysis using R

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I'm running an R script to do a confirmatory factor analysis on my data but I end up with the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 56 Kb`. Is there a problem with my script or the problem is related to my system resources. This is about a questionnaire with 80 items and 5 factors. Here's the code.

```
    library(sem)
    mydata.girls=read.table('data-girls.txt',nrow=150)

    mydata.girls.cov=cov(mydata.girls)

    model.mydata.girls <- specifyModel()
    F1->V1,lam1,.48
    F1->V3,lam3,.53
    F1->V5,lam5,.48
    F1->V14,lam14,.46
    F1->V15,lam15,.57
    F1->V19,lam19,.47
    F1->V24,lam24,.61
    F1->V28,lam28,.56
    F1->V29,lam29,.54
    F1->V31,lam31,.62
    F1->V38,lam38,.44
    F1->V40,lam40,.60
    F1->V42,lam42,.43
    F1->V44,lam44,.55
    F1->V46,lam46,.44
    F1->V48,lam48,.68
    F1->V54,lam54,.53
    F1->V63,lam63,.49
    F1->V64,lam64,.53
    F1->V65,lam65,.58
    F1->V66,lam66,.53
    F1->V69,lam69,.42
    F1->V80,lam80,.45
    F2->V6,lam6,.62
    F2->V9,lam9,.47
    F2->V13,lam13,.43
    F2->V17,lam17,.47
    F2->V36,lam36,.51
    F2->V37,lam37,.61
    F2->V45,lam45,.69
    F2->V49,lam49,.58
    F2->V53,lam53,.61
    F2->V56,lam56,.58
    F2->V57,lam57,.63
    F2->V60,lam60,.61
    F2->V62,lam62,.61
    F2->V67,lam67,.57
    F2->V68,lam68,.55
    F2->V71,lam71,.62
    F2->V74,lam74,.49
    F2->V75,lam75,.72
    F3->V4,lam4,.63
    F3->V7,lam7,.52
    F3->V11,lam11,.66
    F3->V18,lam18,.64
    F3->V25,lam25,.64
    F3->V30,lam30,.63
    F3->V32,lam32,.67
    F3->V33,lam33,.56
    F3->V35,lam35,.56
    F3->V39,lam39,.49
    F3->V43,lam43,.56
    F3->V47,lam47,.54
    F3->V50,lam50,.62
    F3->V52,lam52,.55
    F3->V77,lam77,.60
    F3->V78,lam78,.56
    F3->V79,lam79,.67
    F4->V10,lam10,.59
    F4->V20,lam20,.70
    F4->V23,lam23,.48
    F4->V26,lam26,.78
    F4->V34,lam34,.72
    F4->V41,lam41,.72
    F4->V58,lam58,.73
    F4->V59,lam59,.70
    F4->V70,lam70,.69
    F4->V72,lam72,.78
    F4->V73,lam73,.48
    F4->V76,lam76,.72
    F5->V8,lam8,.73
    F5->V21,lam21,.74
    F5->V22,lam22,.63
    F5->V51,lam51,.56
    V1<->V1,e1,NA
    V2<->V2,e2,NA
    V3<->V3,e3,NA
    V4<->V4,e4,NA
    V5<->V5,e5,NA
    V6<->V6,e6,NA
    V7<->V7,e7,NA
    V8<->V8,e8,NA
    V9<->V9,e9,NA
    V10<->V10,e10,NA
    V11<->V11,e11,NA
    V12<->V12,e12,NA
    V13<->V13,e13,NA
    V14<->V14,e14,NA
    V15<->V15,e15,NA
    V16<->V16,e16,NA
    V17<->V17,e17,NA
    V18<->V18,e18,NA
    V19<->V19,e19,NA
    V20<->V20,e20,NA
    V21<->V21,e21,NA
    V22<->V22,e22,NA
    V23<->V23,e23,NA
    V24<->V24,e24,NA
    V25<->V25,e25,NA
    V26<->V26,e26,NA
    V27<->V27,e27,NA
    V28<->V28,e28,NA
    V29<->V29,e29,NA
    V30<->V30,e30,NA
    V31<->V31,e31,NA
    V32<->V32,e32,NA
    V33<->V33,e33,NA
    V34<->V34,e34,NA
    V35<->V35,e35,NA
    V36<->V36,e36,NA
    V37<->V37,e37,NA
    V38<->V38,e38,NA
    V39<->V39,e39,NA
    V40<->V40,e40,NA
    V41<->V41,e41,NA
    V42<->V42,e42,NA
    V43<->V43,e43,NA
    V44<->V44,e44,NA
    V45<->V45,e45,NA
    V46<->V46,e46,NA
    V47<->V47,e47,NA
    V48<->V48,e48,NA
    V49<->V49,e49,NA
    V50<->V50,e50,NA
    V51<->V51,e51,NA
    V52<->V52,e52,NA
    V53<->V53,e53,NA
    V54<->V54,e54,NA
    V55<->V55,e55,NA
    V56<->V56,e56,NA
    V57<->V57,e57,NA
    V58<->V58,e58,NA
    V59<->V59,e59,NA
    V60<->V60,e60,NA
    V61<->V61,e61,NA
    V62<->V62,e62,NA
    V63<->V63,e63,NA
    V64<->V64,e64,NA
    V65<->V65,e65,NA
    V66<->V66,e66,NA
    V67<->V67,e67,NA
    V68<->V68,e68,NA
    V69<->V69,e69,NA
    V70<->V70,e70,NA
    V71<->V71,e71,NA
    V72<->V72,e72,NA
    V73<->V73,e73,NA
    V74<->V74,e74,NA
    V75<->V75,e75,NA
    V76<->V76,e76,NA
    V77<->V77,e77,NA
    V78<->V78,e78,NA
    V79<->V79,e79,NA
    V80<->V80,e80,NA
    F1<->F1,NA,1
    F2<->F2,NA,1
    F3<->F3,NA,1
    F4<->F4,NA,1
    F5<->F5,NA,1
    F1<->F2,F1F2,0.69
    F1<->F3,F1F3,0.67
    F1<->F4,F1F4,0.61
    F1<->F5,F1F5,0.57
    F2<->F3,F2F3,0.74
    F2<->F4,F2F4,0.54
    F2<->F5,F2F5,0.47
    F3<->F4,F3F4,0.60
    F3<->F5,F3F5,0.52
    F4<->F5,F4F5,0.69

    mydata.girls.sem <- sem(model.mydata.girls, mydata.girls.cov, nrow(mydata.girls))
    summary (mydata.girls.sem)
    std.coef(mydata.girls.sem)
```

Comment: @joran The size of the vector in the post you linked is an order of magnitude greater than here, are you sure the same issue is at play?

Comment: @hexafraction Yes. The way that error message works is that R has _already_ filled up all available memory, and now has attempted to allocate some additional X amount of memory. The additional amount could be very large or very small, all that matters is that it's beyond what's available.

Comment: @joran Ah, I see. I just came across this from the moderation flag queue and saw the discrepancy. I am in no way familiar with R.

Comment: @hexafraction No worries. It's actually a very common question in R, and sadly there's often very little you can do other than get more RAM (and use 64 bit, rather than 32 bit, if you're on Windows).

Comment: have you looked into using the package lavaan instead?

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe No, but I am wondering of using that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's a heck of a model with 80 variables, and is your sample size 150?